# installing windows 8 on mac

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, windows

I am trying to install windows 8 on my mac osx yosemite using boot camp.
I created the bootable usb myself and will download windows assistance software later.So I ticked gthe last option only.
Problem is when the system reboots for installing windows it is not accepting the partition which was earlier created for windows.
I have even tried formatting it from windows setup.
How to solve this issue?